# Two foreign keys from 1 table ON DELETE and ON UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, onupdate

I'm creating a website, and I want to allow users to give reputations one to another. So I have 2 FOREIGN KEYs referencing to User table.

[image]

With this, I cannot apply ON DELETE and ON UPDATE on CASCADE on both CONSTRAINTS - it allows me to do it on one only. So this gives me a problem, I cannot delete my user and to delete all given and taken reputation automatically. It doesn't even let me delete a user at all. Any advice?

Comment: What server is this, mysql?

Comment: No, it's SQL Server.

Comment: Ok, tweak the tags then

Comment: If you want to see a soft delete, for mysql, I will post that.

Comment: My bad. Any idea on problem? Should I go with "NO ACTION" and then, before actually removing an User from database, remove stuff that he did first(posts, reports, voteup/downs, reputations, etc..)?

Comment: What is a "soft delete" though?

Comment: You mark a user row as inactive, other parts of your code know not to display the user. But the row remains

Comment: You don't think Stackoverflow actually deletes users, do you ?

Comment: Yeah, it crossed my mind. But it will create me bigger problem, cus user would like to delete everything that he did on website when he deletes the account, and with that, i will have users with bigger reputation, even tho the user that did the reputation does not exist. But I guess I could try. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Just delete the stuff you want deleted, soft-delete the user, set his rep to whatever you want, etc etc. FK chain will still be honored

Comment: Anyway, I was looking if anyone has a solution, because I'm sure I'm not the only one that uses 2 foreign keys from same table in other table. I'll figure it out with that "soft delete" I guess. Thanks. EDIT: Yes, I'm gonna do that.

Comment: Well that is what people do if you want to honor the FK(s) going into the same table :p  Edit: it is possible to allow NULL on some setups.